# mysql CONVERT_TZ inconsistent behavior

Tags: mysql, sql

The following behavior puzzles me. My mysql server is installed on a PC with EEST timezone.
I want to convert a datetime in mysql to UTC date.

When executing

```
select CONVERT_TZ('1970-01-01 02:00:01', 'SYSTEM', '+00:00')
```

the reponse is:
'1970-01-01 00:00:01'

Similarly, when executing

```
select CONVERT_TZ('1970-01-01 04:00:00', 'SYSTEM', '+00:00')
```

the response is:'1970-01-01 02:00:00'

However, when I basically want the 0 unix time, by executing:

```
select CONVERT_TZ('1970-01-01 02:00:00', 'SYSTEM', '+00:00')
```

The reponse is again: '1970-01-01 02:00:00'

Why is that? Am I doing something wrong? How can I get the correct value which is '1970-01-01 00:00:00'?

Comment: i think you can better replace `SYSTEM` with a + or - timezone like you did for your third parameter.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I agree that this would probably fix the problem.  Yet it's still interesting that this is happening +1.

Comment: @RaymondNijland That doesn't change anything. If I execute select CONVERT_TZ('1970-01-01 02:00:00', '+02:00', '+00:00') I also get '1970-01-01 02:00:00'

Comment: [Documentation to mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) says: "If the value falls out of the supported range of the TIMESTAMP type when converted from from_tz to UTC, no conversion occurs. The TIMESTAMP range is described in Section 11.1.2, “Date and Time Type Overview”. "

Comment: Further it says: "A timestamp. The range is '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC. TIMESTAMP values are stored as the number of seconds since the epoch ('1970-01-01 00:00:00' UTC). A TIMESTAMP cannot represent the value '1970-01-01 00:00:00' because that is equivalent to 0 seconds from the epoch and the value 0 is reserved for representing '0000-00-00 00:00:00', the “zero” TIMESTAMP value. "

Comment: That means that '1970-01-01 00:00:00' is not possible and no conversion occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is that an adjustment made in `CONVERT_TZ` which would result in a timestamp *on or before* the start of the UNIX epoch will be ignored, and the original input timestamp will be returned.  Consider the following three queries:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('1970-01-01 01:00:01', 'SYSTEM', '+00:00');
-- '1970-01-01 00:00:01'
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('1970-01-01 01:00:00', 'SYSTEM', '+00:00');
-- '1970-01-01 01:00:00'
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('1970-01-01 00:30:00', 'SYSTEM', '+00:00');
-- '1970-01-01 00:30:00'
```

Only the first query adjusts the timestamp; the second two just return the input.

From the excellent comments given by @Thomas above, I pulled the following from the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) for `CONVERT_TZ`:

> If the value falls out of the supported range of the TIMESTAMP type when converted from from_tz to UTC, no conversion occurs.

Comment: Thanks. But how I can get the *datetime* 1970-01-01 00:00:00 if the unix value I have is 0?

Comment: @andreas This seems like a departure from your original question.  If you want to add a certain interval of time to the start of the UNIX epoch, then use something like `DATE_ADD('1970-01-01 00:00:00', INTERVAL 0 second)`.

Comment: Not a departure. My question was very clear "How can I get the correct value which is '1970-01-01 00:00:00'?"

Comment: I have answered your questions.